# Should we use verb after as?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

In the following sentence, "A virtual register follows the same format and operation as a physical register", I'm not sure if we should use "as a physical register" or "as a physical register **does**"?

In my mind, "as" is a conjunction when it has the meaning of "similar to".
If we use "like", which is a preposition, we do not need "does".

Is my understanding correct?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The verb may _do_ be omitted, perhaps especially after a large noun group: 'The JEsil Polaroid 320 Color Pack Camera has the same features as the most expensive models.' (from the internet, tidied). / 'Jill uses the same camera as John / me / I do.'

Comment: If you end with ***does***, you can precede the operative noun phrase *(a physical register)* by either ***as*** or ***that*** (but as usual in such contexts, ***that*** can be implied, rather than explicitly stated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shots are exactly right.

This is the natural structure of the verb **Like:** (Which is acting as a preposition in here)

> He speaks like a native speaker - She looks like a supermodel.

This is the natural structure of the conjuction **As:**

> Nobody sings as she does - They went to the party as they were.

According to the site which I will leave bellow, it's very common to use *"As"* rather than *"Like*" and otherwise in American English

[Differences between Like vs. As](https://www.google.com.br/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=Differences%20between%20as%20and%20like&oq=Differences%20between%20as%20and%20like&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.4799j0j7)

This site will explain and help you differ these two terms.

Comment: 'Like' isn't a verb in 'He speaks like a native speaker.' / 'She looks like a supermodel.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I think you are going a little bit out of the focus of the question, I only gave an example, besides, **Like** acts as a verb too, but in those examples, it was performing a preposition's function.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - But thanks anyway, I'm going to change it so that other users won't misunderstand me.

Comment: 'Like' (v) and 'like' (function word) are two entirely different words. See [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/like) etc.

Comment: You might also mean *instincts* rather than *aspects*?